# How Do I Grab Information from MySQL using information from a session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I've set up a really simple shopping cart that I've built and I am having trouble using session information to access a MySQL database.

I'm using sessions to store the `id` and `quantity` for each product that a customer selects, all information that is sent through a form using `$_POST`.  All that works fine.  The snag comes when I then try to take that `ID #` and access my products table in the MySQL db.  I am just unsure of how to call this information out and loop it.

Could you help me out with some possible strategies that I could pursue in order to accomplish my goal?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What problems are you having? if you got as far as the items in a database, to show for selection, you have the knowledge to work through the list of Ids in a session array saying the user wanted them.. Please give some hint as to which bit you're stuck on.

Comment: I am not really sure whether I should use a foreach loop and within that call on the mysql db  within that, or call on the db first and then run a foreach loop

Answer (score 3):

> Could you help me out with some possible strategies that I could pursue in order to accomplish my goal?

Read the PHP manual on how to 'talk' to MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
$productId = $_SESSION['productId'];
$sql = " SELECT * FROM products WHERE productId = '$productId'";
```

You can check the PHP manual to find out how you can perform that query, and then loop through the results. Or just google for a php/mysql tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of IDs, you have some choices.

If the IDs are only stored in an array in a session variable, eg your users cant save them for later. You need to do more work but not a lot.

```
select <stuff> from products where productID in ( 22,56,3683)
```

if you have them in a database you could do

```
select <stuff> from products where productID in (select productID from baskets where userID=34)
```